Anywhere I can get a plain pure tomato sauce?
I’m using a lot of tomato sauce at the moment but not much time for cooking.
Ideally I want tomato sauce, preferably organic, and perhaps some herbs like basil would be ok but pure tomato sauce alone is enough and I could add anything else later.  I certainly do not want lemon, starches or preservative acids etc added.
Most product seem to have things added it’s proving hard to find a pure tomato sauce as I have described. It’s quite easy to find pure organic tomato purée(paste in us) and tomato juice but not pure tomato sauce.
So anywhere I might be able to buy the product I’ve described??
If not I guess the most minimal way to make this product would be to mix uk puree(paste in US) with water and perhaps simmer it for a little?  Would this work or will it have to be cooked from scratch with long times?
Thanks.

What exactly is your objective? Do you want to be able to quickly make a sauce taste like it has been simmered for hours, or do you just want to make a sauce as quick as possible without it still tasting uncooked?

Much of the canned (not bottled) tomato sauce in the US is just tomato paste and water (possibly with some more citric acid, and sometimes with some herbs or spices).  I know people who use it as an ingredient in chili or similar, but as an actual pasta sauce, it's pretty plain... which might actually be what you want

I wonder if this is a regional question. In the US we just have cans labeled "tomato sauce" that contain tomatoes, salt, perhaps some garlic and onion powder, and an acidifier. Really cheap and easy to find, though frankly the taste leaves something to be desired.

I'm very surprised by your question. The whole point of tomato sauce is to not be pure. It's a product for those who want a prepared food that tastes of more than just tomatoes, to go straight to the plate, so you should expect it to be seasoned.

When you buy tomato sauce you are getting a pre-made tomato sauce rather than tomatoes. It's something you can heat and add directly to pasta, it's not an ingredient in a sauce, so it's going to have garlic, herbs, salt, etc. If you want 'unadulterated' tomatoes to make your own sauce you want to get canned whole, crushed, chopped or puree.
Making a basic tomato sauce yourself takes minutes, I personally never buy a pre-made sauce as there's no point, you're spending extra money for something you can do yourself, and better. A bit of olive oil in a pan, fry chopped garlic for about thirty seconds, then put in a can of tomato puree (or passata in the UK), a pinch of whatever herbs are on my mind that day (usually oregano and/or basil) and a few twists of pepper. Bring it up to a bubble for 2 minutes, and it's done. It takes less time than to boil the pasta.
With tomatoes you get what you pay for. Cheap tomatoes have added water (usually in the form of tomato juice, which is red water with a hint of tomato flavor) to reduce their cost, and often have additives to make them seem more tomatoey. Most grocery store chains will have decent canned tomatoes, provided you can shell out for them. Many tomato products have acidity regulators, every whole canned tomato I've seen has added acid, I expect this is because there's more water in the end product so it needs some extra.
For recipes that matter, in the UK I wait for Mutti tomatoes to come on sale and then buy loads, but I haven't seen that brand in the US. In the USA I buy Cento if I can, with Tuttorosso a close second. If you look at their cans of chopped or pureed tomatoes you'll see one ingredient: tomatoes. However, if you can't get or afford those a cheaper can with a dollop of paste will give you a decent result.
I would not recommend basing a sauce on reconstituted tomato paste, as paste has a lot of tomato flavor cooked out. But, if that's all you have you can make it work.

Home made sauce like that freezes well, so I make big batches, which don't take much longer than cooking smaller amounts. Last night I ate one portion and froze 4, for example. That used both tinned and passata (with onion, garlic, black pepper, herbs from the garden, and a little concentrated puree fried lightly before adding the liquid)

GdD, Regarding your second paragraph wouldn’t this just leave a watery sauce(release juice water and cook the pasata a bit)? From what I’ve seen tomato sauce recipes call for at least 1.5 hours simmering.

If you are using good quality tomatoes there's no extra water that needs to be cooked off @JamesWilson. It doesn't make a watery sauce at all. When make pasta I add the almost cooked pasta to the sauce in a pan and cook it together, and I add a couple of scoops of pasta cooking water to it. When I make a meat sauce I do cook it for a couple of hours, that's to soften the meat and make all the flavors meld.

@ChrisH that's a good model. I almost always make at least a double recipe of most dishes and freeze the extra, saves a lot of extra effort down the road.

I like buying Mutti where I live for the exact reasons you describe. I've compared to other brands and it's the one that gives my sauces the best flavor.

They taste good straight out of the can @Luciano, don't they?

@JamesWilson I've made tomato sauce using overly juicy tomatoes (varieties that aren't typically used for salads or sandwiches, not sauce making).  My solution is to add extra hot peppers (as they tend to be overly sweet), then just cook the pasta directly in the sauce.  It takes longer, as you're cooking in an acidic liquid, but it pulls water out of the sauce much easier than cooking it for hours.  There are also plenty of quick cooked tomato sauce styles.  ('Marinara' used to be 'in the style of the sailers', and was specifically a quick cooked sauce)

Italian company Pomi offers chopped, strained, and pureed tomato products that contain only tomatoes and salt. Its organic line of these products contains only tomatoes, no salt.
According to Pomi, it offers:

controlled supply chain
traceability of the tomatoes from shelf to field
production process sustainability
processing sustainability

Searching buy pomi should bring up some buying options for you.

While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - From Review

Edited. This answer directly addresses OP’s question “Anywhere I can get a plain pure tomato sauce?... preferably organic” and as well provides a link-free search option.
